# How can I run a JavaScript function across all of my website different pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to implement some sort of counter of how much time a user spend on my website and display it on the contact page.
So far I got this little piece of JavaScript code:

```
var time = 1;
function timeHere() {
    time = time + 1;
    finalTime = time / 10;
    document.getElementById("counter_container").innerHTML = "You've just spend "+ finalTime + " seconds looking at my homepage.";
}
```

And I execute it using `setInterval(timeHere(), 100);`
Unfortunetaly it just write 0.2 second and I guess is because the `setInterval` method is running just once and I have to look for a way to loop it.
But the main issue that I am facing is how can I make the `timeHere` function run across all the different pages of the website and still counting the seconds.
I want to host this project using Github Pages so a PHP solution will not help me that much in this case.

Comment: try looking at cookies and sessions with JS :) a quick google on cookies and JS should hopefully show you the way :D

Comment: Since, JS is client side, your tools are limited only to cookies or local storage.

Comment: Try a [worker](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp) on background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can really run a javascript call that will affect all pages simultaneously. At the very least, I don't think that's the best solution to this problem.

Set a cookie (or use local storage) for the user. Use some kind of token (if they are logged in maybe an ID, if not maybe IP) and then

```
$.cookie(user, time_spent)
```

Then simply += the time to the time_spent for that user cookie.

Also, there's a bazillion similar tracking tools. I'm sure if you don't want to homebrew your own version, google analytics would probably do this for you in a few minutes.